# Flutter how receive data with httpServer

Tags: flutter, http

I use this class https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/HttpServer-class.html .I want to get data in function listen from input text in html. How can i do this ?
I have to use this class https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.2/dart-io/HttpRequest-class.html
but i don't know how.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.